# How do I troubleshoot the installation of Apache Accumulo on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I am trying to install open source Accumulo on RHEL 7.x. I have two GB of swap space. I have installed Java 1.8, Hadoop 3, and Zookeeper. I have run the bootstrap_config.sh script for Accumulo 1.9.2.

I ran this (and expected it to work):

```
/bin/accumulo-1.9.2/bin/accumulo init
```

But I get this error:

> [start.Main] ERROR: Uncaught exception
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.apache.accumulo.start.spi.KeywordExecutable: Provider
>   org.apache.accumulo.proxy.Proxy could not be instantiated
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
>           at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main.checkDuplicates(Main.java:237)
>           at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main.getExecutables(Main.java:228)
>           at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main.main(Main.java:84) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
>           ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader$2.loadClass(AccumuloClassLoader.java:294)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 10 more

I used the Accumulo bootstrap_config.sh script to configure Hadoop version 3.  How do I get "/bin/accumulo-1.9.2/bin/accumulo init" to work?

Answer (score 1):

Accumulo 1.9.2 expects Hadoop 2 out of the box, but does have a build profile to rebuild a tarball specifically for use with Hadoop 3. You can build Accumulo with the Hadoop 3 profile by downloading the source tarball and doing:

```
mvn clean package -Dhadoop.profile=3 -DskipTests
```

If you're not interested in rebuilding from source, it may be possible to simply fix the class path issues by reading the error message, and adjusting your class path accordingly. In this case, it seems you're missing a commons-configuration jar.

Comment: I used the ./bootstrap_config.sh to specify Hadoop version 3.  When I try the command above, I get "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/usr/bin/accumulo-1.9.2/bin). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory."  What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run the build command from a location other than the root of the source tree. To rebuild from source, you have to start by obtaining the source release tarball from the download page.

Comment: I obtained the accumulo-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz file.  I uncompressed the files into a new directory /opt/.  I then entered this directory I ran the command you provided.  It failed the same way with the same error.  I believe this is considered to be from the "root of the source tree."  What is the "root of the source tree"?

Comment: That's the binary tarball. You need to download the source tarball. (The one with "-src" in the name.)